# JVM could not be loaded on windows 7 using LoadLibrary() function from VC++

Tags: windows-7, loadlibrary

I am facing one problem in my application as following:

Java classes from my application uses JRE6 files for execution so I have bundled JRE6 folder in my application. An exe from my application loads JVM using function: Loadlibrary(jvm.dll's path).  This works fine on XP but on Windows 7 machine an error is being thrown - "Unable to load JVM error."
What could be the issue?  any suggestion?

This error disappears on Windows 7 machine if I bundle the above exe(exe from my application) with JRE6 folder at the following path: 
JRE6/bin/MyExe.
It seems that exe is able to find its JVM dependencies at the path - JRE6/bin/MyExe. But would it be JRE6 Copyright and Licensing violation if I bundle my exe with JRE6 and distribute it along with my application.

NOTE: Exe from my application only loads JVM and does not add/modify/delete any file from JRE6 folder.

Answer (score 0):

please, try this.
Reinstall the program that uses the jvm.dll file. If the jvm.dll DLL error occurs when you use a particular program, reinstalling the program should replace the file.